# Ler elementos da matriz e imprimí-los

Tags: javascript, array, matriz

Criei um algoritmo que recebesse uma única variável com 9 registros diferentes que exibisse estes valores digitados na forma de matriz (tabela). Mas ao exibir o resultado, está apenas retornando os três últimos valores em três linhas seguidas.

```js
var numero = Array(3,3);
  var x,y;
  for (x = 0; x < 3; x++) {
    for (y = 0; y < 3; y++) {
      numero[x,y] = parseInt(prompt("Digite o "+[y+1]+"º número da "+[x+1]+"º coluna"));
    }
  }
  for (x = 0; x < 3; x++) {
    for (y = 0; y < 3; y++) {
      document.write(numero[x,y]+"&nbsp&nbsp");
    }
    document.write("<br>");
  }
```

Neste caso, qual seria a forma mais correta para exibir os 9 valores que o usuário digitou corretamente e na forma de matriz?

Comment: De declaração. Em JavaScript não criamos uma matriz com `Array(3, 3)`. Veja a [documentação no MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Sintaxe). E você também não acessa uma posição com `[x, y]`, você precisa criar um *array* de *array*.

Comment: Esta documentação não deixou a minha dúvida muito clara, pois em um eixo de coordenadas, eu pensei que a sintaxe do Array poderia ser escrita com parênteses (). Eu observei alguns artigos aqui na internet, mas eu não consegui chegar a nenhuma conclusão a respeito dessa sintaxe feita com colchetes [][] que é bem diferente da que eu aprendi na teoria. Você poderia colocar um exemplo prático a respeito dessa sintaxe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conforme explicado [nos comentários](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/349473/erro-de-declara%c3%a7%c3%a3o-de-comando-ou-de-l%c3%b3gica#comment702469_349473), de acordo com a [documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Sintaxe), quando você faz `Array(3,3)`, você está criando um array com 2 elementos (e ambos os elementos são o número `3`):

```js
let arrayCom2Elementos = Array(3, 3);
// array com 2 elementos
console.log(arrayCom2Elementos); // [3, 3]
// tamanho do array
console.log(arrayCom2Elementos.length); // 2
```

---

Em JavaScript nativo não existem matrizes propriamente ditas (embora existam [bibliotecas](https://www.google.com.br/search?q=+javascript+matrix+lib) para isso), mas você pode simplesmente criar um array de arrays: primeiro você cria um array, e depois faz com que cada elemento dele também seja um array.

Para isso você pode usar `Array(3)`, pois segundo a [documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Sintaxe), quando apenas um número é passado para o construtor, este é usado como o tamanho do array.

Depois você faz um loop neste array, e faz com que cada elemento seja outro array de 3 elementos:

```js
let matriz = Array(3); // array com 3 elementos

// cada elemento é outro array com 3 elementos
for (let i = 0; i < matriz.length; i++) {
  matriz[i] = Array(3);
}
console.log(matriz); // cada elemento é um array de 3 elementos
```

Outro detalhe é que, para acessar os elementos da "matriz" (que na verdade é um array de arrays), não se usa a sintaxe `[x, y]`. Primeiro você faz `matriz[x]`, que retorna o array da posição `x`. E como `matriz[x]` também é um array, para acessar a posição `y` dele basta fazer `matriz[x][y]`.

---

Resumindo, seu código ficaria assim:

```js
let dimensao = 3; // dimensão da matriz (assumindo que ela é uma matriz quadrada)
let matriz = Array(dimensao); // array com 3 elementos

// cada elemento é outro array com 3 elementos
for (let i = 0; i < matriz.length; i++) {
  matriz[i] = Array(dimensao);
}

let linha, coluna;
for (linha = 0; linha < dimensao; linha++) {
  for (coluna = 0; coluna < dimensao; coluna++) {
    matriz[linha][coluna] = parseInt(prompt("Digite o " + (linha + 1) + "º número da " + (coluna + 1) + "º coluna"));
  }
}

for (linha = 0; linha < dimensao; linha++) {
  for (coluna = 0; coluna < dimensao; coluna++) {
    document.write(matriz[linha][coluna] + "&nbsp&nbsp");
  }
  document.write("<br>");
}
```